# JSON nested array

Tags: c#, json, facebook

Lets say i have the following JSON

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "from": {
            "name": "aaa bbb",
         },
         "actions": [
            {
               "name": "Comment",
               "link": "http://...
            },
            {
               "name": "Like",
               "link": "http://.."
            }
         ],
      },
```

And i have

```
JSONObject wallData = helper.Get("/me/feed");
if (wallData != null)
{
    var data = wallData.Dictionary["data"];
    List<JSONObject> wallPosts = data.Array.ToList<JSONObject>();
}
foreach (Facebook.JSONObject wallItem in wallPosts)
{  ... }
```

Which stores me whole feed into wallData and 'data' object into wallPosts.
So then i can access the `wallItem.Dictionary["from"].Dictionary["name"]`, and i get "aaa bbb".
But i can't get inside the actions array
The wallItem.Dictionary["actions"].Dictionary["name"] doesn't work.

Any idea

Answer (score 1):

You need to do something like `wallItem.Dictionary["actions"][0].Dictionary["name"]` because "actions" is an array.

Comment: Ok... so i put this into a Foreach
`ViewData["hm"] = wallItem.Dictionary["actions"][0].Dictionary["name"].String;`
It underlines me `wallItem.Dictionary["actions"][0]`, error saying "Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type Facebook.JSONobject"
Any idea

Comment: I don't know how a Facebook.JSONobject works - maybe `wallItem.Dictionary["actions"].Array[0].Dictionary["name"]`?

Comment: Maybe a (wallItem.Dictionary["actions"])["name"] would help. Cast if necessary...

Answer (score 0):

On a different note...its neater if u directly into a class...like this

```
var jSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var jsonObject = jSerializer.Deserialize<DataObject>(json);
```

The DataObject will be a class which emulates ur JSON data in a strongly typed class. Depending on the size of ur Json you will not have to use a lot of strings in your code.